# How to install python libxml2 in solaris?

Tags: solaris

I'm good at installing package in Linux environment but newbie to Solaris OS. I need to install Python - libxml2 package to my project. Does the below command also work in Solaris server for installation??

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev
```

I have tried googling, unfortunately not able to get.

Answer (score 1):

What you proposed is specific to Debian-based Linux distributions.

IMHO, the fastest way would be to download the libxml2 source code in order to compile and install it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Solaris 11, then `pkg install libxml2` with sufficient privilege would be the right invocation.  Determining the right package name is as simple as `pkg search` with a reasonable query (assuming that you're still connected to the repository from which you installed the system).

If you're running Solaris 10 or older, then you'll need the original install media, plus whatever patches have been issued that intersect `SUNWlxml`. But frankly, installing from source is probably easier at that point.